# Uninstall Scangearmp

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall "scangearmp-mx340series-1.50-1-i386-deb". I have installed it using Archive Manager for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It is not working so i want to uninstall ALL installed items of the Package.

Thank You

Comment: post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep scangearmp`

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
sudo apt-get remove —purge name
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Replace `name` with whatever the name of the software you are trying to remove